# How to change user for the repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket

There are plenty of questions similar to this, but I still can't change the user for my repository.

I am using password authentication. I have modified local config for the repository to set new user name and email.

```
git config user.name
```

is displaying a correct (new) user i want to use. But all the commands are still accepting previous user password and not a new one. Is there anything else I should check/modify?

Comment: The user.name property is not the user name that you use to authenticate against the remote. The user name is the name of the person that created the commit

Comment: @klaustopher, do you know where should I set the user name to authenticate against the remote?

Comment: Usually this is set in the remote ... Something like `https://username@bitbucket.org`. Look at the `.git/config` file or use `git remote -v`

Comment: @klaustopher, please put this as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user.name` Setting is for the name that is associated with your commit, not the user name you use to authenticate with the system.

The default BitBucket clone URL puts the username in the remote URL. You can check this by looking at the `[remotes]` section in `.git/config` or by checking `git remote -v`